# Why does a Java while loop that asks for user input using scanner skip the first input

Tags: java, while-loop, java.util.scanner

I am trying to get user input until a blank field is entered and the enter button is pressed. My while loop skips the first input, I have tried looking around but I dont understand how to fix it or use an better method.

```
public static void main(String[] args){

      Container x = new Container();
      Scanner scanner = new Scanner(System.in);
      String input = scanner.nextLine();

      while (!input.equals("")) {   
            input = scanner.nextLine();            
            x.addWord(input);         
            } 
      x.display();

    }
```

[image: input and output]

Comment: Obviously because you are calling `input = scanner.nextLine();` twice before doing anything with the `input`.

Comment: Thats what everyone says but I dont understand how to fix it

Comment: *I dont understand how to fix it* - don't call it twice?

Comment: how about moving `x.addWord(input);` before `input = scanner.nextLine();` inside the loop?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You read a line before entering the loop, and then immediately in the first line of the loop's body read another line. You should move the read to the end of the loop's body:

```
String input = scanner.nextLine();
while (!input.equals("")) {   
    x.addWord(input);
    input = scanner.nextLine();            
}
```

Comment: Thanks for your time in explaining this. How is addWord() adding the entered input when it is being called before the scanner that reads the user input.

Comment: @DanA If you read the full code, `scanner.nextLine` is called once before the loop...

Comment: Thanks guys. I thought the first line was just for initialization and the inputs would only start inside while loop.